# Dynamic Inputs not getting serialized / submitted

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dom, serialization

i have the following form in  a modal (beside other modals on the page) (shortened for reading).

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-project" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit-project">
  <form method="POST" action="update" id="edit-project-form">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Project Metadata</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <label>People:</label>
        <div class="form-group row" data-rel="0">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" name="member[0][firstname]" type="text" value="John">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <input class="form-control" name="member[0][lastname]" type="text" value="Smith">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control" name="member[0][email]" type="text" value="john@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input class="form-control" name="member[0][uri]" type="text" value="http://www.example.com">
        </div>
      </div>

      ...

      <div class="form-group row" data-rel="2">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" name="member[2][firstname]" type="text" value="Peter">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <input class="form-control" name="member[2][lastname]" type="text" value="Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control" name="member[2][email]" type="text" value="peter@example.com@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input class="form-control" name="member[2][uri]" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button class="add-form-group btn btn-default" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>                
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Works great except for the last button from which I call some JQuery to dynamically add inputs. My plan was to make it the most general possible and prevent any HTML in the JS by cloning the form-group the button sits in and including it after the current form-group:

```
$('div.modal-body').on('click', '.add-form-group', function(){
    var current_form_group = $(this).closest('.form-group');
    var next_form_group = current_form_group.clone();
    var current_index = current_form_group.data('rel');
    var next_index = current_index + 1;

    next_form_group.attr('data-rel', next_index);


    next_form_group.children().find('input').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).attr('name').replace(current_index, next_index);
        $(element).val = '';
    });
    $(this).parent().remove();
    next_form_group.appendTo('#edit-project-form').insertAfter(current_form_group);
})
```

The form group is generated well. But the newly created inputs never get posted (not even serialized) although the elements are visible via DevTools:

```
<div class="form-group row" data-rel="3">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" name="member[3][firstname]" type="text" value="New Firstname">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input class="form-control" name="member[3][lastname]" type="text" value="New Lastname">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" name="member[3][email]" type="text" value="New Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input class="form-control" name="member[3][uri]" type="text" value="New URI">
    </div>                                                            
</div>
```

Trying to find the form to append the new form-group to is not successful:

```
// Does not work:
var form = current_form_group.closest('form');
// Neither does this:
var for = $(this).closest('form');
```

How can I get the parent form? But am I doing wrong? I queried for it and most of the time it was a problem with a wrongly wrappend form element (which is not the case here).

Serialization happens client-side so far and works well with the original inputs:

```
$('#edit-project-form').bind('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form    = $(this);
    var div     = $(this).parent();

    console.log(form.serialize());
});
```

**UPDATE:** I gave more information on where the code actually sits (a modal). I left out any server-side code since the serialization already fails client-side

**UPDATE 2:** I got it working now:

```
form.append(next_form_group);
```

The only thing that puzzles me now is the following: It gets injected at the top of the form now. How can I move the created form-group right underneath the "current_form_group". An easy "insertAfter" (like in the original post) does the trick visually but doesn't append the new form-group to the form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you serialising the form data? Have you checked what is being generated and what's being received by the server?

Comment: I use JQuery as well for serialization (form.serialize). It works well for the original inputs but not for the generated ones.

Comment: It works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0djm9saq/. The issue must be somewhere in your code which is why I left the previous comment. You haven't shown enough of your code, or given enough information about the problem, to be able to help you

Comment: Thanks Rory, I added some more details. Your fiddle works fine. Since the whole serialization happens client-side (so far), i guess this is really a JQuery-related problem especially with the dynamic binding (maybe I don't understand it fully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

```
next_form_group.appendTo('#form').insertAfter(current_form_group);
```

you are using `insertAfter` which add the data after the div having id `#form` and the `form` tag ends inside the div having id `#form`.

So to handle this use `append()` to add dynamic html inside `form` tag

Comment: My mistake - I edited my post. Of course, I append to the form not the DIV :)

Comment: No. I updated my original post with some more information. I have no clue what's going wrong.

Comment: thanks for your input. Got it almost working. See my edit of the original post for my final question :) Thanks.

Comment: Means you want the new html should go on the last?

Comment: No, right behind the "current form group" which could be anywhere in the form. Possible?

Comment: Yes, you can `append`, `after` any selected container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139848/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-fab-fuerste).